# Solution to reverse Nth integer excluding leading zero

Tags: java, reverse

how to modify this programme to print reverse number of integer excluding leading zero.

```
class Solution {
    public void solution(int N) {
        int enable_print = N % 10;
        while (N > 0) {
            if (enable_print == 0 && N % 10 != 0) {
                enable_print = 1;
            }
            else if (enable_print == 1) {
                System.out.print(N % 10);
            }
            N = N / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int n = 2340; int res = Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(n)).reverse().toString()); System.out.println(res);`

Answer (score 0):

> *how to modify this programme to print reverse number of integer excluding leading zero.*

One way is to re-construct the number in reverse. Use a long for the result to prevent int overflow.

```
int n = 12340;
long res =0;
while(n > 0){
   res = res * 10 + n%10;
   n/=10;
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Prints

```
4321
```

**Note:**  Had the number `Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647)` been used, the result would have been `7463847412`.  Had I used an `int` for the result, the result would have been `-1126087180` because the reversed value will not fit into an `int`, resulting in integer overflow.